# Logarithm of identity matrix

Tags: matrix-exponential

What are the possible $n \times n$ matrices such that $e^X = I$? Some obvious ones are $X = 2\pi i m I$ for integer $m$. Are there others and do they have some kind of group structure?

Comment: A simple extension would be any diagonalizable matrix with eigenvalues taking values in $\{2\pi i m| m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, which is not closed under addition or multiplication.

Comment: Hints to get you started: What values might you put on the diagonal of a diagonal matrix $X$? $e^Xe^Y = e^{X+Y}$ if $X$ and $Y$ commute.

Comment: And matrices similar to the ones in the @whpowell96 comment.  Are there others?  Investigate the Jordan form.